# Como cadastrar data de nascimento no bd?

Tags: php, banco-de-dados

Como cadastrar data de nascimento no bd?

[image: Erro]

Codigo que pega do form:

```
$data = $_POST['dtn'];
$dataP = explode('/', $data);
$dataBd = $dataP[2].'-'.$dataP[1].'-'.$dataP[0];
```

função que envia os dados para o bd:

```
<?php

include("conecta.php");

function insereUsuario($conexao, $dataBd) {
    $query = "insert into usuarios (dataBd) values ({$dataBd})";
    return mysqli_query($conexao, $query);
}
```

Comment: Já tentou colocar aspas no comando SQL: `('{$dataBd}')`? Sem elas o banco irá interpretar como valores inteiros e efetuar a operação de subtração 2015-10-20 = 1985.

Comment: Amigo obrigado, era aspas, desculpa o erro meu e obrigado novamente por ter me ajudado.

Comment: se a coluna for do tipo `Valores de Tempo` não vai haver soma não

Answer (score 1):

A declaração Insert dependendo do tipo de dados da coluna pode gravar um valor conforme mostrado abaixo.

**1 - Sem aspas no valor**

SQL, sendo a coluna `dataBd` do tipo `Valores de Tempo`

```
insert into usuarios (dataBd) values (2015-10-20)

Resultado (tipo DATE): 0000-00-00

Resultado (tipo DATETIME): 0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

---

---

SQL, sendo a coluna `dataBd` do tipo  `Valores String` ou `Valores  Numéricos`

```
insert into usuarios (dataBd) values (2015-10-20)

Resultado: 1985
```

---

---

**2 - Com aspas no valor**

SQL, sendo a coluna `dataBd` do tipo  `Valores String`

```
insert into usuarios (dataBd) values ('2015-10-20')

Resultado: 2015-10-20
```

---

---

SQL, sendo a coluna `dataBd` do tipo  `Valores Tempo`

```
insert into usuarios (dataBd) values ('2015-10-20')

Resultado (tipo DATETIME): 2015-10-20 00:00:00

Resultado (tipo DATE): 2015-10-20
```

---

---

SQL, sendo a coluna `dataBd` do tipo  `Valores  Numéricos`

```
insert into usuarios (dataBd) values ('2015-10-20')

Resultado: 2015
```

### Conclusão

Para colunas do tipo tempo ou string coloque aspas no valor

```
$query = "insert into usuarios (dataBd) values ('{$dataBd}')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Tenta adicionar aspas data que vai pra query.

```
insert into table (dt) values('2017-10-26');
```

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia
Faço do seguinte modo a INSERÇÃO de valores no DB. (mysql)

```
$pid_paciente=$_POST['pid_paciente'];
$pid_horario=$_POST['pid_horario'];
$pdata_consulta = $_POST['pdata_consulta'];
$sql =  " Insert into consulta " .          
        " ( id_paciente_fk, id_m_h_fk,  id_convenio_fk, data_consulta)" .
        " values " .
        " ( ".$pid_paciente.",".$pid_horario.", 0,'" .$pdata_consulta. "')";


$resultado = mysql_query($sql, $conexao) or die(mysql_error());
```

Isso é 100% GARANTIDO :).
Para UM insert dar errado temos varios motivos. Mas na sua pergunta esta DATA DE NASCIMENTO e o erro só esta retornando o ANO. 
AO que parece a variável $_POST['dtn'] só tem o ano dentro.
Para verificar o que esta dentro do $_POST['dtn'] eu faria assim:

```
$data = $_POST['dtn'];
echo $data . ' a<br>';
$dataP = explode('/', $data);
echo $dataP . ' a<br>';
$dataBd = $dataP[2].'-'.$dataP[1].'-'.$dataP[0];
echo $dataBd . ' a<br>';
exit;
```

Espero que tenha dado alguma luz a ti :)
Abraços.